# freezing and getting this on every boot: kernel: intel_soc_dts_thermal: request_threaded_irq ret -22

Tags: boot, 16.04, kernel, intel, freeze

I use Ubuntu 16 alongside win 10 on lenovo g50-70 (intel chipset)

I get this line on every boot,

```
kernel: intel_soc_dts_thermal: request_threaded_irq ret -22,
```

I was wondering if this is related to the freezing of my Ubuntu.

It has been freezing from the day I installed it but I installed `liquorix  kernel` and it froze rarely.

Every time it freezes, I get a 'clearing orphaned inode' message at boot

But I can still use Ubuntu without any problem

Comment: I too am getting occasional hangs and I see this error message. Though, I've seen the message come up and the system keeps running, but that doesn't invalidate it. Also, I don't think my system's getting particularly hot. I've seen it hang when very little is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error: "kernel: intel_soc_dts_thermal: request_threaded_irq ret -22" comes from the Intel SoC DTS Thermal driver.  It requests a threaded irq handler and for some reason one of the parameters to the kernel function request_threaded_irq() are invalid and it returns error -22 EINVAL, "Invalid parameter".  From what I can intuit from the code, it is most likely that the interrupt is invalid or the settings requested are not valid.  As it stands, this error means that some thermal zone trip point information cannot be read, so it may affect the ability to measure and/or control the systems temperature.

Since this driver is not running (because of the initialization failure), the only affect it can have is perhaps being able to control thermal overrun (for example via thermald), but that kind of issue would manifest itself in a machine shutdown on thermal overrun, which you are not seeing, hence I don't think it is related to your machine hang.